# IP has my listed in wrong state... how do I change this?

Tags: ip, search, search-engines, geolocation

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this question, but my IP has me listed in Nebraska, and I'm in Atlanta, GA. It's becoming a nuisance because every search engine shows me Nebraska results and gives the wrong times for things (because I'm EST, and the city in Nebraska it has me listed in is CDT). Any idea on how to change this? Thanks!

Comment: Use a search engine that allows you to set your location, but the location of the owner of an ip adress, is handled by that owner.  The owner of your ip address, could be registered in Nebraska, even with your ISP being in GA.  That isn't unheard of.

Comment: I'm going to see if there's a way to set my location. It's with Google, so I'm sure there is. I did a quick check on https://www.iplocation.net/ to see the geolocation info, and sure enough, most of them say Nebraska. I mean, it's not the end of the world, but it's just an unnecessary pain in the butt. :)

Comment: @Burgi - Yep! Seems to be the same question. I guess, in short, the answer to my question is: "No. You can't change this." :) I'd up your comment, but I don't have enough points. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

ISP's don't map their IP's to geographic locations and enter that in a central Internet-wide database. GeoIP databases are usually based on collected and aggregated data entered by users on websites. Because of that, they are usually not very accurate and the data is collected by several companies. Unless you know which geolocation provider's data the website you are using is using and contacting them directly, it seems you're out of luck.

Another common occurence with this system is that IP blocks are sometimes moved to another location (an ISP changes the addressing plan, or they run of IP's in a specific location, taking IP's from somewhere else). This would list the location of these IP's in databases wrong until the database is updated.

There is this famous story of someone being delayed into the US because the geolocated IP of the internet connection they used to book was mapped to IS(IS) (Jordan) controlled territory, while in fact the booking was made from the UK ([Source](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fdecorrespondent.nl%2F2675%2FDit-gebeurt-er-allemaal-achter-de-schermen-als-je-naar-de-VS-vliegt%2F130264475-b9f887ba&edit-text=)).

Comment: A famous story that is less then 8 years old, thats a new record, ;-)

Comment: Slightly less dramatic, but when my ISP shifted my class A address to a new block, I moved from London to Birmingham for a month :/